# Total Unique items in col B for user ID x

Tags: google-spreadsheets

Tried everything i can think of that google suggests, will copy and paste a few here for review, but simply put. I have a string of text as an ID say "id-1" I'm trying to count the number of unique items in a column where the row also has this unique ID

in the table below i'm looking to say user id-1 has 3 fruit types, essentially. the data i'm given also has blanks in there, which seems to break a lot of the suggestions i found googling.

**id** 
 **fruit**

id-1 
 apple

id-1 
 apple

id-1 
 banana

id-2 
 apple

id-2 
 banana

id-2 
 apple

id-1

id-1

id-1 
 pear

tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(P:P>="id-1"),--(P:P<="id-1"),N:N)

=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF("id-1"=$P:$P,1/(COUNTIFS($P:$P,"id-1",$N:$N<>"",$N:$N<>"")),0)))

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(P:P="id=1",N:N),N:N)>0,1))
```

Not my area of expertise so i'd appreciate any guidance. Using Google Sheets, not Excel.

Comment: no fruit type would be the blank. When doing the suggested functions i found via google I get a division by zero error b/c of the blank cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, although I want to warn against using the entire column style reference, as array formula calcs are processing intensive. If you know your data ranges going in, set the ranges to the bounds of the data.

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A:$A="id-1",IF($B:$B<>"",MATCH($B:$B,$B:$B&"",0))),ROW($B:$B)-ROW($B$1)+1),1)))
```

The "id-1" will need to be changed if you have lots of id's you wish to perform the lookup for, you could put those unique ID's in another column, reference that column instead of the hard-coded "id-#" and leave the $ anchors out and copy the formula down.

**What it's doing:**

```
IF($A:$A="id-1",
```

Figures out if each row in the range matches the given string, "id-1"

```
IF($B:$B<>"",
```

then if so, checks only non-blank cells in the fruits column

```
MATCH($B:$B,$B:$B&"",0)
```

and finds the row index of the first found occurrence of each string

```
FREQUENCY(IF($A:$A="id-1",IF($B:$B<>"",MATCH($B:$B,$B:$B&"",0))),ROW($B:$B)-ROW($B$1)+1
```

Then finds how many unique fruits exist

```
IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A:$A="id-1",IF($B:$B<>"",MATCH($B:$B,$B:$B&"",0))),ROW($B:$B)-ROW($B$1)+1),1)
```

And correlates the unique values to those found in the first three code snips above to get a total count of each unique value, then assigns each found string with a single 1 count to flag that it was found for the current ID.

```
SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A:$A="id-1",IF($B:$B<>"",MATCH($B:$B,$B:$B&"",0))),ROW($B:$B)-ROW($B$1)+1),1))
```

And finally, sums up all the found strings for that ID